# Is using Notepad++ for file reading and writing still reliable when I deal with large amount of data?

Tags: file, file-io, notepad++

I am doing a program that has a database (ebean, sql) but I store data in a file. Per line I have an instance of a class and their fields next to them separated by a space. When my data (instances of a class and attributes/fields) gets bigger, is Notepad++ still reliable for file reading and writing? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You might want to clarify how big your files are going to get. Notepad++ reliably reads decent-sized files for me, but if you're talking about GB-sized files I can't offer an opinion.

Comment: Thank you! Let's just say any `.txt` file. Are they reliable? Because when this project is already uploaded to the server, I won't be opening Notepad++ anymore.

Comment: .txt files can be more or less any size as far as I'm aware. I've not personally dealt with any above a few MB, though, and the files you'll need to worry about will probably be in the > 2 GB range. Actually, you might have responsiveness issues before that, since Notepad++ is slow to open MB-sized files. But I don't think reliability will be affected until you get into the GBs.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is reliabe for middle size files, but note

- it may not work for 100-200+ MB file size, program may hang.
- it may slowdown reading and saving files bigger than 5-10 MB. But file contents should be saved and loaded OK.

Better use **EmEditor** for big files.

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, if this project is released and uploaded to the server, will loading, reading, and writing still be okay even if the file size gets larger (say up to 300MB then GB)?

Comment: No, 100-300MB size is NOT ok for N++.

Comment: Thanks. I just don't get it. When this project is done, I'm not going to physically open Notepad++ to check the content. So does this mean that the speed depends on the default program for `.txt` files? Sorry for sounding stupid. :)))